# SQL Server - CASE on where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case, where-clause

I'm working on a stored procedure that is a select query. Under the `WHERE` clause I am filtering the return results to return only if there is a `PageTitle= 'STA'`

Here is am example of my query :

```
@InputCountryId INT, 
@InputIndustryId INT


AS 
BEGIN

SELECT 
      r.IdCountry,
      r.IdIndustry,
      r.PageTitle, 
      r.IndustryName

From dbo.Reports r

WHERE 
     r.IdCountry = @InputCountryId
     r.IdIndustry = @InputIndustryId
     r.PageTitle = 'STA'
END
```

The ending condition `r.PageTitle` I would like it to be applied ONLY IF `InputCountry = 1` if not; do not include the filter.

I've attempted this by including a `CASE`. I am having a syntax error any time I try and introduce this case. Is this something that is possible? Am I implementing it incorrectly?

Here is an example of the stored proc with the `CASE` included.

```
    @InputCountryId INT, 
    @InputIndustryId INT
    
    
    AS 
    BEGIN
    
    SELECT 
          r.IdCountry,
          r.IdIndustry,
          r.PageTitle, 
          r.IndustryName
    
    From dbo.Reports r
    
    WHERE 
         r.IdCountry = @InputCountryId
         r.IdIndustry = @InputIndustryId
CASE WHEN @InputCountryId = 1 THEN
         r.PageTitle = 'STA'
END



    END
```

Comment: `CASE` can't return the result of boolean expressions, as SQL Server doesn't have a boolean datatype.  Instead, it needs to return a literal value to be used *within* a boolean expression. Such as `CASE WHEN @InputCountryId = 1 THEN r.PageTitle ELSE 'STA' END = 'STA'`

Comment: The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
WHERE 
     r.IdCountry = @InputCountryId and
     r.IdIndustry = @InputIndustryId and
     (@InputCountryId <> 1 or r.PageTitle = 'STA')
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need case statement. You can use `OR` clause

```
 WHERE 
     r.IdCountry = @InputCountryId
     r.IdIndustry = @InputIndustryId
     (@InputCountryId != 1 OR r.PageTitle = 'STA')
```

this only filters PageTitle with STA when InputCountry is 1

Answer (score 0):

I can't test with your data, but here is a CASE in a WHERE clause that works.

```
DECLARE @Variable INT = 3

SELECT GETDATE()
WHERE 1 =
  CASE
    WHEN @Variable = 1 THEN 1
    WHEN @Variable = 3 THEN 1
    WHEN @Variable = 5 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
```